# Graphical drag-n-drop designer library for C# applications?

Tags: c#

I have an app that my users use to build objects.  For example, they will create a "user" object and add properties (name, address, etc).

I would like to use an environment like the one Visual Studio uses on its class designer or entity designer.

Is there a library out there that will help me with this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Visualization and Modeling SDK](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vsvmsdk). This helps you build a graphical DSL. Among other things, it comes with a template for a "class designer" DSL. You can start from there, and modify as needed.

Comment: does the V&M SDK come with any documentation? i can't find any

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx

Comment: thanks John! So the docs seem to indicate that this SDK is specifically for building tools that integrate with Visual Studio. Do you know if can be used for creating standalone applications? (I.e., tools that don't require Vis Studio at runtime.) I'm creating a tool that requires a graphical, animated visualization, of a simulation model. I'm trying to determine if this library would be appropriate for this task. I'm not familiar with DSLs.

Comment: Although the docs are from the point of view of Visual Studio, the tool can be used to create "standalone" applications. The tool produces several artifacts: an XML schema defining the format for serializing instances of the model; an API for interacting with instances of the model; one or more user-defined T4 templates, driven by the API, which can be used to produce any text-based artifacts based on an instance of the model; and finally, a Visual Studio item template that can be used to add instances of the model to a Visual Studio project.

Comment: You've been extremely helpful, John. If I could bother you just once more: do you think that this tool could be used to create an animated front-end for a complex HMI simulator (with animations driven by the underlying simulator/model)? In other words, users will create a diagram representing an industrial system, then hit a "Start" button and be able to view an animated workflow as it migrates through the system diagram. In OTHER words, can it be used as the View in a MVC (Model-View-Controller) application?

Comment: You could use this to generate a view from the model. You'd use the tool to graphically design the model of the system, then it could generate the .cshtml file corresponding to the view. In fact, you could add instances of the model directly to the MVC project, and it would generate the .cshtml file corresponding to the model instance.

Comment: For an example of an older DSL used within a Visual Studio project, see http://csd.codeplex.com/.